# System.IO.FileSystemWatcher and mapped network drives

Tags: powershell

I use following PowerShell script to monitor a mapped drive for newly created files and write these changes to a csv file.

```
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = 'Z:\'
$action = 
{
    $path = $event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
    $changetype = $event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
    Write-output "$path was $changetype at $(get-date)" >> C:\temp\HostFileList.csv
    
}


Register-ObjectEvent $watcher 'Created' -Action $action
 
Get-EventSubscriber

while($true){ sleep -seconds 1 }
```

The computer I'm running this script on is heavily used by multiple users. Each user will log onto the computer with their own profile, click a desktop batch file to map a network drive folder and save their work there. My script is set up in Local Group Policy to be ran at start up. From what I can tell the script doesn't have any issues running in the background and listening to the mapped drive folder. My problem is that the script refuses to write an output file to the designated location. If I manually run the script, it creates the output file just fine. Also, when I manually run the script with the local GP startup script enabled, I get two entries in my file, which makes me believe the script is running fine from the local GP. Could anyone advise why my script creates an output file when I run it manually, but not when it is ran at startup? Any feedback is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for this...

```
Write-output
```

> [Write-Output (Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output?view=powershell-7)
>
> Sends the specified objects to the next command in the pipeline. If
> the command is the last command in the pipeline, the objects are
> displayed in the console.

Use the file cmdlets

```
Export-Csv
Out-File
```

... and the -append parameter. So, collect your properties and pipe to one of them.

```
 | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\temp\HostFileList.csv' -Append -NoTypeInformation
```

> [Export-Csv (Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7)
>
> Converts objects into a series of comma-separated value (CSV) strings
> and saves the strings to a file.

```
$AppService = (Get-Service -DisplayName *Application* | Select-Object -Property DisplayName, Status)
$AppService | Export-Csv -Path .\Services.Csv -NoTypeInformation
Get-Content -Path .\Services.Csv
$WinService = (Get-Service -DisplayName *Windows* | Select-Object -Property DisplayName, Status)
$WinService | Export-Csv -Path ./Services.csv -NoTypeInformation -Append
Get-Content -Path .\Services.Csv

"DisplayName","Status"
"Application Layer Gateway Service","Stopped"
"Application Identity","Running"
"Windows Audio Endpoint Builder","Running"
"Windows Audio","Running"
"Windows Event Log","Running"
```

> [Out-File (Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility) - PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-7)
>
> Sends output to a file.
>
> -Append Adds the output to the end of an existing file.

Comment: Thank you. I will try the file cmdlet and follow-up with my results.

Comment: No worries, glad it all worked out for you. Take care.